# Calculate content area in jquery before and after toggle

Tags: jquery, css

I'm create a layout where I need to calculate the content area height to keep header and footer area visible. But the thing is, I've included show hide using toggle. So my content area is fine while the toggle is off. But if the toggle is on, I cannot calculate the height of content area. Please check my code below and help me to sort out. Thanks.

```js
$(".toggleLink").click(function(){
 $(".wrapper").toggle();
});
var winHeight= $(window).height()-32;
var headHeight = $("#header").height();
var footHeight = $("#footer").height();
var toggleHeight = $("#showhide").height();
var contentHeight = winHeight - headHeight - footHeight - toggleHeight ;
$("#content").height(contentHeight);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  display: none;
}

#content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="showhide">
  <a href="#" class="toggleLink">Toggle</a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
  <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `position: fixed` in your header, content and footer. I don't just understand what exactly your are trying to achieve..

Comment: instead js can you use css like  height: calc(100% - (60px + 60PX));(if only  the header,footer height is fixed)

Comment: @Hardy, thanks for your suggestion. sorry I cannot use any position as it will be used for responsive purpose. Also the objective is to keep the content area height needs to be adjusted based one the toggle is open or close.

Comment: @mr.cool, thanks for your idea, but i want to do it in pure js to avoid any browser compatibility issues.

Comment: ok.you need content height after toggle and also on page loading time right?

Comment: i think you need write this calculation code once more inside the click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iam not sure your requirement is like this please try this code

```js
 $(function () {
$(".toggleLink").click(function(){
            $(".wrapper").toggle();
   var winHeight= $(window).height()-32;
        var headHeight = $("#header").height();
        var footHeight = $("#footer").height();
        var toggleHeight = $("#showhide").height();
        var contentHeight = winHeight - headHeight - footHeight - toggleHeight; alert(contentHeight)
        $("#content").height(contentHeight);
        });
        var winHeight= $(window).height()-32;
        var headHeight = $("#header").height();
        var footHeight = $("#footer").height();
        var toggleHeight = $("#showhide").height();
        var contentHeight = winHeight - headHeight - footHeight - toggleHeight; alert(contentHeight)
        $("#content").height(contentHeight);
   });
```

Comment: almost done. Last thing, instead $(".wrapper").toggle(); can we make it as $(".wrapper").slideToggle(); ? Please let me know.